# Is there a Simple minimalistic Twitter iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications, twitter

I am searching for an iPhone application that does not show or load the timeline. On my phone, I am just interested in tweeting text and/or photos, and consequently, that's what I want my twitter iPhone to do, nothing more, nothing less.

Now I found a good app for just tweeting, but it doesn't let me tweet photos; it's called Birdhouse, it's a really good app. I also have instagram, but it resizes the photos and forces the user to add all kinds of effects. For mentions, which I also care about, I use Notifio which does an amazing job.

So is there an iphone twitter app that let's the user just tweet text and photos, AND that is up to date (by that I mean that it uses oAuth and has been updated once at least in the last three months)? Otherwise, is there a good minimalistic app that just let's users tweet photos with optional text (no effects, no bloat)?

Comment: Use SMS for just tweeting.

Comment: just wondering why bother? get any app that suits your taste and use it for what you need only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found exactly what you are looking for. It's called [SuperPost](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/superpost/id397792374?mt=8) by, of all people lol,... MySpace. Needless to say, it's free and also can optionally post to Facebook & MySpace simultaneously. It's not too shabby actually.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I like [echofon](http://www.echofon.com/twitter/iphone/) and [simplytweet](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simplytweet-3/id364574174?mt=8). Both of which you can customize to your taste by disabling most, if not all, of other features.

Answer (score 1):

[Weet](http://weetapp.com/iphone/) & Twitterific are the most minimal of everything I have used. Weet is pretty barebones and lightweight, basically the iPhone version of [Itsy](http://mowglii.com/itsy/). I'm a Tweetbot guy, which is a totally awesome app but it sounds like it does way more than you want.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't hyperlink everything, new user.

Comment: You can put links in as full text and then flag it for a moderator to review / edit in the future. Welcome and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Twitterific is as close as you can get to minimalist for an iPhone Twitter App - http://twitterrific.com/iphone/

Comment: I tested Twitterific a bit. While I do agree that among the "regular" twitter clients it's the most minimalistic, compared to what I am actually looking for it's pretty bloated.

It has all the feature of a regular Twitter client, which is exactuly what I
don't want:

- A timeline with all the tweets
- List management
- Twitter search
- etc

All I want is to be able to tweet text and/or images. The solution I am using
now is Birdhouse + yFrog, which is what I was kind of looking for. But I
wouldn't mind having an app that has both functionalities (tweet text and
tweet images)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like Instagram, there's also [Picplz](http://picplz.com/). It does not alter the image, nor does it force you to add a filter.

But it does not let you tweet just text.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [**Weet**](http://weetapp.com/iphone/) as a minimilistic replacement of the official Twitter application.

**Honorable mentions include:**

- [Icebird](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icebird-for-iphone/id354940065?mt=8)
- [Brizzly](http://brizzly.com/iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I love it when apps have as little chrome as possible. Two twitter apps that are gorgeous and minimalistic (and manage to retain tons of functionality) are Osfoora and Icebird.

[Icebird](http://icebirdapp.com/) is great because it has little chrome and there are plenty of options (including picture and video uploading to flickr)

[Osfoora](http://www.osfoora.com/) is great because of its intuitive jump screen, and its minimal tweet composition UI. They also make an iPad version that is absolutely stellar.

Both of these are paid apps though, but I wouldn't hesitate on the $2 or $3 purchase.